# Global set insertion style in Tikzfeynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

How to globally set insertion style using `tikzfeynmanset`?

I tried

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
    every insertion/.style={
        /insertion/style={thick},
    },
}
```

but it won't work.

**MWE:**

This is what effect I expect:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=($(a)!0.5!(b)$)]
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[right=1cm of a] (b);
        \diagram*{ (a) --[insertion={[style=thick]0.5}] (b);};
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this is the code I expect without adding `style=thick` in every occurrence of `insertion`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{
    every insertion/.style={
        /insertion/style={thick},
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=($(a)!0.5!(b)$)]
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[right=1cm of a] (b);
        \diagram*{ (a) --[insertion=0.5] (b);};
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please add a complete MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and illustrates your point? I *guess* you need to say `\tikzfeynmanset{
    every insertion/.style={
        thick
    },
}`, but I am not in the mood to cook up an MWE and check that.

Comment: @marmot MWE added.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is no predefined way of doing this, but if you are willing to slightly redefine the `insertion@@` style, you could do

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\makeatletter
\tikzfeynmanset{  insertion@@/.style args={[#1]#2}{
    /tikz/decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position #2 with {
        \tikzfeynmanset{insertion/.cd,#1}
        \draw [/tikzfeynman/every insertion,\tikzfeynman@insertion@style] (-\tikzfeynman@insertion@size, -\tikzfeynman@insertion@size) -- (\tikzfeynman@insertion@size, \tikzfeynman@insertion@size);
        \draw [/tikzfeynman/every insertion,\tikzfeynman@insertion@style] (-\tikzfeynman@insertion@size, \tikzfeynman@insertion@size) -- (\tikzfeynman@insertion@size, -\tikzfeynman@insertion@size);
      },
    },
    /tikz/postaction={
      /tikz/decorate=true,
    }  
}}
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
\tikzfeynmanset{every insertion/.style={thick,red}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=($(a)!0.5!(b)$)]
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a);
        \vertex[right=1cm of a] (b);
        \diagram*{ (a) --[insertion={0.5}] (b);};
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]